# Can I use the same RoomDatabase object from multiple threads on Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-room

I'm using the Room persistence library on Android. Currently, I have some extra synchronization code each time I access the database. I want to know if this code is necessary.

I currently access the database as a singleton.
This is how I am currently inserting objects into the DB:

```
    // Insert values into DB
    final AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.get(this);
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (db) {
                for (WorkOrder wo : workOrderList) {
                    db.workOrderDao().insertAll(wo);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Do I need to have the insertion code in a synchronized block?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`RoomDatabase` wraps the standard `SQLiteDatabase`, which is fairly thread-safe, with all work being done in transactions.

I would worry less about `synchronized` and more about transactions, as right now, this work is being done in N transactions (one per `WorkOrder`). I would have an `insertAll(List<WorkOrder>)`, so you can perform this in one transaction. Or, if for whatever reason that's impractical, move your loop into the `@Dao` class in its own method, with a `@Transaction` annotation, to indicate that the entire method should be performed in a single transaction.

Comment: Do we have to annotate the CRUD methods with `Flowable`, `Maybe`, `Completable`, etc. for this to work?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: The `@Transaction` annotation does not require any return type, let alone a reactive one. Otherwise, I am not quite certain what "this" is that you are referring to.

Comment: I am referring to OP's code: **db.workOrderDao().insertAll()**

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: If you are literally going to use the OP's code, `insertAll()` needs to be synchronous. Otherwise, the `synchronized(db)` part is pointless.

Comment: @CommonsWare:  "I would have an insertAll(List<WorkOrder>), so you can perform this in one transaction". Does it means that insert(List<>) are automatically put inside a transaction?

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh: AFAIK, each `@Insert` DAO method is its own transaction by default. "Putting this annotation on an Insert, Update or Delete method has no impact because they are always run inside a transaction" (from [the `@Transaction` JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Transaction)).

Comment: @CommonsWare:PCMIIW,  there can be only one write transaction at a time and no other read or write transaction can happen at the same time, so inserting all the data in one transaction instead of N transaction ensures that other read transaction read data only after completion of write transaction. However if we insert data in N transaction, a read transaction might access the database before writing to database is completed( when someone tries to read data after writing and expects that he/she will read the updated data).[sqlite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html).