# Room Thread Management

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Following Android Developer page says:

> By default, all queries (@Query) must be executed on a thread other than the main thread. (You work on that later.) For operations such as inserting or deleting, if you use the provided convenience annotations, Room takes care of thread management for you.

Source: https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-advanced-course-practicals/unit-6-working-with-architecture-components/lesson-14-room,-livedata,-viewmodel/14-1-a-room-livedata-viewmodel/14-1-a-room-livedata-viewmodel.html#task3intro

But this is not correct, right? Room does not automatically run insert and delete operations on a background thread. So what is this sentence supposed to mean?

Comment: please provide valid link because I can't open the one you added above.

Comment: @MenachemBiegun Just corrected the link in the question

Answer (score 1):

It means that those room operations are [thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47532610/3371707) (so you don't have to take care of it if you e.g. run insert/delete operations on different background threads, [source](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/60))

Answer (score 1):

BY default you can't run room operation on the main thread.
You can use `.allowMainThreadQueries()` to run them in the main thread.

```
if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "database")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
```

Or you have to create an `AsyncTask` to perform room queries.

If you are running long-running operations using room you should use `AsyncTask` because running long-running operation on the main UI thread may cause your UI to block.

Answer (score 0):

> if you use the provided convenience annotations, Room takes care of thread management for you.

It means that when you use these Room annotations in the `Dao` interface; Room takes care of these modifications (Update, Insert, and Delete) if they run in different background threads. Room doesn't provide this background thread though; but it can manage multiple requests from different threads.

That is also probably because when using such annotations, each of these methods runs in a separate transaction ([documentation reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Transaction)). a Database Transaction operation is a stand-lone operations that won't affect one another.

Some database systems restrict the use of the same database connection at the same time in more than one thread; Room doesn't, Room takes care of this as it's thread safe.