# What will happen when multiple suspend functions in background service update different rows of SQLite DB simultaneously using Room in Android Studio?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

In my Android Studio project, I am utilizing SQLite with Room for database operations. The background service contains several suspend functions that are responsible for updating rows within the SQLite database.

Considering that SQLite applies table-level locks, it raises the question of what occurs when multiple suspend functions attempt to update different rows of the same SQLite database simultaneously.

Will the SQLite database become locked, leading to a crash in the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when multiple suspend functions attempt to update different rows of the same SQLite database simultaneously.

The suspend functions are not separate threads; they just provide continuation that allows different tasks to run concurrently within a coroutine. Running concurrently doesn't mean simultaneously/in parallel, but run for a short period of time in successive manner.

So, if you update different rows with Room in multiple suspend functions within the same coroutine/job; they actually doesn't run simultaneously.

But, what you'd worry about, is when you run these updates in different threads (different coroutine Dispatchers); Generally speaking, some database systems restrict the use of the same database connection at the same time in more than one thread; Room doesn't, Room takes care of this as [it's thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47525082/can-i-use-the-same-roomdatabase-object-from-multiple-threads-on-android/47532610#47532610) and [support multithreaded](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/60).

Fortunately, Room is Thread Safe, and run each `Dao` method annotated with Room CRUD annotations in a separate standalone database Transaction ([Documentation Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Transaction)).

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that it's safe when I update records in different coroutine Dispatchers with Room?

Comment: @HelloCW Yes, the github issue link exactly discussed that in different threads; coroutine dispatchers are just different threads.

Comment: Also pls. have a look on [For operations such as inserting or deleting, if you use the provided convenience annotations, Room takes care of thread management for you.](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-advanced-course-practicals/unit-6-working-with-architecture-components/lesson-14-room,-livedata,-viewmodel/14-1-a-room-livedata-viewmodel/14-1-a-room-livedata-viewmodel.html#task3intro). This means that you can do these operations on multiple threads, and Room is able to manage these operations in these threads.

Comment: Notice also that only one database write operation can be done at a time; this is what Room guarantees in the previous statement; the ability to manage database modification from different threads/dispatchers.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Room`, you'll be able to update multiple rows at a time. However, keep in mind that if your list of ids contains more than 999 items it may throw an exception:

`SQLiteException: too many SQL variables (Sqlite code 1)`